# Trial+Paid apps in wp7

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, upload, trial

when I implement trial experience in my windows phone silverlight app, I tested it on my device in DebugTrial mode, which I made recently, I want to ask that which XAP file to be upload to marketplace, either of Debug folder or of DebugTrial folder?

Comment: To answer, we would have to know what exactly your 'DebugTrial' mode changes in the code

Comment: DON'T upload Debug versions to the marketplace. Always send a Release package!